# jquery integration issue when attempted to execute on load

Tags: 8, javascript

It may just my limited js experience but until recently I had some js attached to the drupal context on one of my sites to produce some small animation/style effects that took the form:

```
$(window).on("load",function() {
    //do something
})
```

This worked great until recently then suddenly stopped working with no errors or messages. Eventually I got it working by changing the above to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //do something
})
```

Did something change in core or jquery that caused this? Why would there be no errors? I use the first `$(window).on()` successfully on at least two other sites but have not been able to figure out why it stopped working on this one.

Some of the js I wish to run relies on the entire page being fully loaded so I really would rather use `$(window).on()`- which I believe triggers later.

I am using the latest release version of drupal 8

Comment: Drupal 8.4 introduced jQuery 3.x - which may be why things "stopped working" if they previously worked before as there are breaking changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reviewing @hugronaphor's answer. In particular [this link](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/understanding-javascript-behaviors-in-drupal) along with some jQuery 3.x discussions regarding changes to the ready and load events my final solution was in fact to remove my code from `Drupal.behaviours`.

In the end I have implemented code in the following style:

```
(function ($, Drupal){
    $(window).on("load",function() {
        //Do something
    });
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

This gave me reliable access to the `.on("load")` event again which is what I was after as I need the entire page to be loaded before I trigger the script.

As my script is relatively simple and doesn't need further context information I think this is fine for my use case.

I "think" the issue is related to the [following change](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3194) in jQuery 3.x where `on("load")` is not guaranteed to fire inside a `$(Document).ready` state any more - which is what `Drupal.behaviours` is giving you. I am something of a js noob though so will leave it to smarter people to explain why this may or may not be the case. If there is a better answer I would like to hear it.

For my simple case not being in the `Drupal.behaviour` has solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

As @Kevin mentioned

> Drupal 8.4 introduced jQuery 3.x

And according to [jQuery Core 3.0 Upgrade Guide](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-on-quot-ready-quot-fn-removed)  the "ready" event has been removed.

What you should do is to implement your functional code in `Drupal.behaviours`. This would have the similar effect as `$(document).ready()` but with more [benefits](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/understanding-javascript-behaviors-in-drupal).

```
(function ($, Drupal) {

  Drupal.behaviors.myHandler = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      // do something
    }
  };

})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Comment: So sorry If I wasn't clear about this in my question but my code is already wrapped in a drupal behaviour/context. I've always thought I had to call window.on("load") events inside that context. That has - and continues - to work on my other sites just on this site the window.on('load') event is not triggering inside the Drupal.behaviour